# finding the latest available version of libraries

Tags: android, repository, android-support-library

I'm trying to add support libraries to my Android studio project.
studio suggests to use "27.1.1" version of appcompat library but is not available in jcenter or google repository.

my questions:

1.How can I find the latest available version of libraries?
2.why jcenter does not include support libraries(http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.1.1 this page is not found)

thank U every one

Comment: is your build.gradle file setup correctly? https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup

Comment: allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // add this line 
        }
    }
}

Comment: I have download android support library repository but it doesn't have the newer versions (just till 25.3.1)

Comment: when I added (maven.google) I could not build because of this error :Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.4.0/appcompat-v7-25.4.0.pom'. (and it is 404 not found)